# VSCode ESP-IDF framework esp32 SPIFFS error

Tags: embedded, microprocessor, flash-memories, esp32

I’ve beet trying for days and days now to make SPIFFS work on my esp32 board using PlatformIO in VSCode following the following example: https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/storage/spiffs but I can’t just make it work.
If I use the Arduino framework it will mount the partition without any problems but when I try to do it with ESP-IDF framework it just wont create the partition nor reformat flash memory if doesn’t find the partition I’m looking for.

the logs are as follows:

> ```
> I (28) boot: ESP-IDF 3.30300.190916 2nd stage bootloader
> I (29) boot: compile time 23:32:31
> I (37) boot: Enabling RNG early entropy source…
> I (37) boot: SPI Speed : 40MHz
> I (38) boot: SPI Mode : DIO
> I (42) boot: SPI Flash Size : 4MB
> I (46) boot: Partition Table:
> I (50) boot: ## Label Usage Type ST Offset Length
> I (57) boot: 0 nvs WiFi data 01 02 00009000 00006000
> I (64) boot: 1 phy_init RF data 01 01 0000f000 00001000
> I (72) boot: 2 factory factory app 00 00 00010000 00100000
> I (79) boot: End of partition table
> I (83) esp_image: segment 0: paddr=0x00010020 vaddr=0x3f400020 size=0x08e64 ( 36452) map
> I (105) esp_image: segment 1: paddr=0x00018e8c vaddr=0x3ffbdb60 size=0x01ec4 ( 7876) load
> I (108) esp_image: segment 2: paddr=0x0001ad58 vaddr=0x40080000 size=0x00400 ( 1024) load
> I (113) esp_image: segment 3: paddr=0x0001b160 vaddr=0x40080400 size=0x04eb0 ( 20144) load
> I (129) esp_image: segment 4: paddr=0x00020018 vaddr=0x400d0018 size=0x19444 (103492) map
> I (165) esp_image: segment 5: paddr=0x00039464 vaddr=0x400852b0 size=0x033cc ( 13260) load
> I (176) boot: Loaded app from partition at offset 0x10000
> I (176) boot: Disabling RNG early entropy source…
> I (177) cpu_start: Pro cpu up.
> I (180) cpu_start: Application information:
> I (185) cpu_start: Project name: vetable
> I (190) cpu_start: App version: 1.0.0
> I (195) cpu_start: Compile time: Nov 28 2019 23:32:36
> I (201) cpu_start: ELF file SHA256: 0000000000000000…
> I (207) cpu_start: ESP-IDF: 3.30300.190916
> I (213) cpu_start: Starting app cpu, entry point is 0x40081e0c
> I (0) cpu_start: App cpu up.
> I (223) heap_init: Initializing. RAM available for dynamic allocation:
> I (230) heap_init: At 3FFAE6E0 len 0000F480 (61 KiB): DRAM
> I (236) heap_init: At 3FFC0A80 len 0001F580 (125 KiB): DRAM
> I (242) heap_init: At 3FFE0440 len 00003AE0 (14 KiB): D/IRAM
> I (249) heap_init: At 3FFE4350 len 0001BCB0 (111 KiB): D/IRAM
> I (255) heap_init: At 4008867C len 00017984 (94 KiB): IRAM
> I (261) cpu_start: Pro cpu start user code
> I (280) cpu_start: Chip Revision: 1
> W (280) cpu_start: Chip revision is higher than the one configured in menuconfig. Suggest to upgrade it.
> I (283) cpu_start: Starting scheduler on PRO CPU.
> I (0) cpu_start: Starting scheduler on APP CPU.
> I (294) SPIFFS:
>
> Initializing SPIFFS
> E (304) SPIFFS: spiffs partition could not be found
> E (304) SPIFFS: Failed to find SPIFFS partition
> ```

and my code is the following:

```
//standar freeRTOS
#include <stdio.h>
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "esp_spi_flash.h"
#include "driver/gpio.h"
#include "sdkconfig.h"
#include "freertos/queue.h"

//spiffs
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include "esp_err.h"
#include "esp_log.h"
#include "esp_spiffs.h"
#include "spiffs_config.h"



//----------SPIFFS SETUP-----------//
void vfsSetup(){
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "\n\nInitializing SPIFFS");

    esp_vfs_spiffs_conf_t conf = {
    .base_path = "/vetable",
    .partition_label = NULL,
    .max_files = 5,
    .format_if_mount_failed = true
    };

    // Use settings defined above to initialize and mount SPIFFS filesystem.
    // Note: esp_vfs_spiffs_register is an all-in-one convenience function.
    esp_err_t ret = esp_vfs_spiffs_register(&conf);

    if (ret != ESP_OK) {
        if (ret == ESP_FAIL) {
            ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to mount or format filesystem");
        } else if (ret == ESP_ERR_NOT_FOUND) {
            ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to find SPIFFS partition");
        } else {
            ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to initialize SPIFFS (%s)", esp_err_to_name(ret));
        }
        return;
    }


    vTaskDelay(100/portTICK_PERIOD_MS);

    size_t total = 0, used = 0;
    ret = esp_spiffs_info(NULL, &total, &used);
    if (ret != ESP_OK) {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to get SPIFFS partition information (%s)", esp_err_to_name(ret));
    } else {
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Partition size: total: %d, used: %d", total, used);
    }

};



//----------MAIN----------//
void app_main(void){
   vfsSetup();
   return;
}
```

The following is my platformio.ini file:

```
;PlatformIO Project Configuration File
;
;   Build options: build flags, source filter
;   Upload options: custom upload port, speed and extra flags
;   Library options: dependencies, extra library storages
;   Advanced options: extra scripting
;
; Please visit documentation for the other options and examples
; https://docs.platformio.org/page/projectconf.html

[env:esp32dev]
platform = espressif32
board = esp32dev
framework = espidf
monitor_speed = 115200
```

Comment: To use SPIFFS, you must partition the flash memory such that space is allocated for SPIFFS? What partitioning are you using? Please show the `platformio.ini` file. Also see: https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/platforms/espressif32.html#partition-tables

Comment: @Codo I believe you're completely right, that was my main suspect. My question now would be, in VSCode, where in my project would I have to put my partition table?

Comment: I guess you got your answer by now: https://community.platformio.org/t/vscode-esp-idf-framework-esp32-spiffs-error/10817/4

Answer (score 1):

Define partition table in platform.ini like this:

`board_build.partitions = custom_16MB.csv`

Inside file is something like :

`Name,   Type, SubType, Offset,  Size, Flags`

`nvs,      data, nvs,     0x9000,  0x5000,`

`otadata,  data, ota,     0xe000,  0x2000,`

`app0,     app,  ota_0,   ,        0x640000,`

`app1,     app,  ota_1,   ,        0x640000,`

`spiffs,   data, spiffs,  ,        0x370000,`

This is my partition table for 16Mb ESP32.

*How to define custom partition tables:*

https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/partition-tables.html

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer for this issue as stated in the following thread: https://community.platformio.org/t/vscode-esp-idf-framework-esp32-spiffs-error/10817.

The problem was basically I was trying to access a partition that never existed in my partition table. I downloaded the csv file from the example and placed it in the root directory (where platformio.ini is located) then I was able to access the "spiffs" partition to store data